# Free Memory from GtkListStore in C

Tags: c, memory, gtk

How do I free memory allocated from GtkListStore ?
I Understand the Concept of creating Tree Views, creating models, fill them with data and so on.

For Example:
Treeview is created with 2 Columns with G_TYPE_STRING.
Lets say i fill the rows in a loop n-times with data like so

```cpp
gtk_list_store_append( model, &iter);
gtk_list_store_set( model, &iter, COL_1, "STRING", COL_2, "ANOTHER STRING", -1);
```

These Strings get copied to the List Store.
Now up to my Problem.

Lets say I have created 50.000 Rows and want to drop 30.000 and fill the others with new Strings.

```
gtk_list_store_clear( GTK_LIST_STORE( model ) );
for( int c = 0; c < i; c++){
    gtk_list_store_append( model, &iter );
    gtk_list_store_set( model, &iter, COL_1, "NEW STRING", COL_2, "ANOTHER NEW STRING", -1);
  };
```

When this is done multiple times the memory just keeps increasing.

Setting the Model to NULL doesn't work.
Removing the iter doesn't work.

The List Store still holds the old Data. Is there a way of releasing the internal of the List Store, or should I use G_TYPE_POINTER in the model instead ?

Comment: [GtkListStore actually *does* free the old strings when you change rows](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtktreedatalist.c?id=9d0febc9a64a5bfb0fcfc3a88de4757f6c1ff090#n236) (and also when you clear the list, but you have to follow `gtkliststore.c` to see it). There's another leak in your program somewhere...

Comment: Am I wrong, or free's it only the old String and with g_value_dup_string() a new allocated copy of the new String is created ? I don't wont to " replace " the String, i want to change the List Store from say, 2500 items to maybe only 10 . When I clear the Store, are the old strings still in list->data.v_pointer ?

Comment: No; all the old data should have been destroyed; see the files I linked and named for details. What is your actual code?

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/kJnq12u1)  This is what i try to do. maybe I'm doing it totally wrong.